# Using Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in for loop (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, infinity

How would the following code behave, especially when the double counter reaches its limit ((2-2^-52)·2^1023)?

```
for (double i = 0; i < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; i++){
    //do something
}
```

Would this code behave as expected (loop forever) or fail at some point and why?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd argue that there's no guarantee that it'll make it to that value. Who's to say that `i` won't underflow before you reach that value due to the way that double arithmetic behaves?

Comment: Why not just try it ?

Comment: @Makoto That's basically what I'm asking. The only interesting case here is the edge case.

Comment: I'm not sure I see this as "interesting" per se...If you want an infinite loop, is there any good reason to avoid `while(true)`?

Comment: @Makoto Well in my current situation the variable it compares against can either be a normal value or infinity in case you want to run the loop forever. I saw this as the easiest most convenient way to make this happen.

Comment: "In case you want to run the loop forever"?  Again, I defer to, "Why are you avoiding `while(true)`?"

Comment: @Makoto because I can't do while(counter)? This is Java, not C. I'm not going to make two different loops when I can just use one.

Comment: I feel like there is something deeply wrong with the design of the program if you're relying on the fact that floating-point arithmetic won't increment smoothly *just* to get an infinite loop out of it.  But I think I'll stop pestering you from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will never exit the loop.

The reason for this is that adding `1` to a sufficiently large `double` number does not change its value:

```
double a = 1.7976931348623155E308;
double old = a;
a++;
System.out.println(a);      // prints 1.7976931348623155E308
System.out.println(old);    // prints 1.7976931348623155E308
System.out.println(a==old); // prints "true"
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/NCg92J)

In fact, when the value of `double` gets sufficiently close to positive infinity, you need to add a number well above 10<sup>200</sup> in order to make your large double change value and become `POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

The reason for this is the way `double` represents large numbers. It uses a short *mantissa* to represent the most significant digits of the value, and an exponent to indicate where the fractional point should be placed. In case of very large numbers, the exponent is essentially an indication of how many zeros need to be added after the binary representation of the mantissa.

In order to make your `double` number change value through addition, you need to add a number that is at least as large as the least significant bit of the mantissa. Once the binary exponent goes above 48, the smallest number that you need to add in order for the result to be different becomes 2, meaning that `++` would no longer change the value.

Comment: Does it have completely 0 effect? No change in bits or memory? Or will it have an effect after a large number of ones?
Also what does "sufficiently large" exactly mean?

Comment: @Samir Adding one to a large number has no effect. Once the floating point unit sees that the exponents of the two numbers being added puts their mantissas into non-intersecting ranges, the unit stops, and returns the value of the larger number.

Answer (score 6):

At some point, `i++` will stop having any effect, because for very large values of `i`, consecutive `double` values are far apart.

Therefore it is an infinite loop.

To prove there are `double` values for which `i == i + 1` try this:

```
for (double i = 1;; i *= 2){
    if (i == i + 1) {
        System.out.println(i); 
        break;
    }
}
```

It prints

```
9.007199254740992E15
```

Comment: That's interesting, didn't know that. Does the increment stop having effect forever or it just takes a really long time to see a change? Also would the counter ever overflow with this loop?

Comment: @Samir it doesn't have an effect ever.  It's not "secretly" preserving the increase somewhere; there is no change at all once `i` gets big enough.  Once `i` gets to that value, it _stops changing entirely_.

Comment: @Samir Floating point values don't have infinite resolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place is the minimum "step" you need to go. At this point that's larger than 1

Comment: @LouisWasserman okay makes more sense now, thank you. What if the counter was an integer? Would it just overflow and still loop infinitely?

Comment: @Samir integral types `int`, `char`, `byte`, `short` and `long` all overflow. If you add one to e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you get `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. No value of an integral type has `i == i + 1`.