# Is Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY a true representation of infinity?

Tags: java, infinity

I was wondering if Java's 'Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY' is a true representation of infinity and, if not, will 'i' from this code:

```
public class Infinity {
private static int i;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double inf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    for (i = 0; i < inf; i++) {
      }
    System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

Ever be printed?

Comment: What do you mean with a "true" representation of infinity? That value is defined as a representation of infinity for the type `double`. But you cannot store infinity in an `int`; there is no value that represents infinity for the type `int`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529676/using-double-positive-infinity-in-for-loop-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you change your code to

```
double inf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for (double i = 0.0; i < inf; i++) {
}
System.out.println(i);
```

The loop will never end, since `i` can never become larger than `Double.MAX_VALUE`, and `Double.MAX_VALUE` is still smaller than `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

You can prove it by running this snippet:

```
if (Double.MAX_VALUE > Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
  System.out.println ("max is larger than infinity");
} else {
  System.out.println ("nope");
}
```

which will print "nope", since `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is larger than any possible double value. BTW, the compiler marks the `System.out.println ("max is larger than infinity");` statement as dead code.

I guess this means you could say `'Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY' is a true representation of infinity`.

BTW, the value of `POSITIVE_INFINITY` is

```
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;
```

Therefore, since 1.0/0.0 is actually positive infinity, you can say it's a true representation of infinity.

Answer (score 5):

`i < inf` will always be `true`; i.e. `i` will never reach `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

That's because `int` will overflow to a negative once it reaches 2,147,483,647.

Note that even if `i` was a `double` type, you still wouldn't attain `POSITIVE_INFINITY`: that's because after the 53rd power of 2, certain single increments are a no-op.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior: it will overflow to `-2,147,483,648` and then start over.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: My, what is wrong with me today? I was convinced this was C++. Was just about to embark on IEEE754 limits etc.

Comment: I guessed as much :)

Answer (score 1):

int has 4 bytes. It ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650505/what-is-the-inclusive-range-of-float-and-double-in-java) for example).

Which is **way** smaller than Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY.
( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317566/what-are-the-infinity-constants-in-java-really) ).

So your loop simply runs over and over and over ...

And a more "philosophical" bonus answer: why do you need to ask other people?! You learn programming by making **experiments**. *Yourself*.

In other words: that inner curious to "try and find out" is what helps you becoming a programmer. Asking for clarification is fine; but asking for explanations *without* you trying anything is the **wrong** approach. Doing so *slows* down your learning!